# Need tooltip solution... with extras

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

I have seen tons of jquery/css/js tooltip solutions out there but I need one which will act as a tutorial when a user lands on my site.

e.g. When they log in for the first time a tooltip will show next to e.g. content area 1, then have a link ("Next" or something) in the tooltip which closes that one then spawns another at content area 2 and so on... but also with the ability to stop the tooltips.

Does this type of thing exist? Can it be done?

And would I store this in a cookie so as to only show it once?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Usually you are looking for somethinge like guiders-js.
Check out [the project on Github](https://github.com/jeff-optimizely/Guiders-JS)
and a live demo [here](http://jeffpickhardt.com/guiders/).

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't know what the site are you develop, but if there are a lot of tutorial when a user land your site, this will be a very tedious and annoy user experience. The best way to show the next step is make the site intuitive and no thinking about the "next step". There was a book talking about it and may help you [***Don't Make Me Think***](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321344758).

Comment: Although this is a good proposal, you're not actually answering the OP's question.

Comment: Thanks @Anzeo - I also did say I need to be able to close it at any time, and only want to show it once.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/#) which enables you to create Facebook style tooltips.
You can configure the tooltips to contain HTML and you can also manually trigger them (so without having to hover over the link).

You could then chain your tooltips by having a link in each one that will trigger the next one. The link above contains a tutorial on all the features of tipsy, so be sure to check it out.

I agree on your idea to use a cookie to determine whether or not to show the tips.